# .exe does not run with more than one instance of "../" in the path

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, command-line

## Issue

I have a Release-compiled MSVC C++17 "server" application. I usually make a child process from the client application to run a local server, so I use a relative directory path for the command line to execute as the child process. I am emulating that call here by typing in the relative path manually in powershell from where the client application executable runs.

It seems running `run_Server.exe` works with a command line like:

```
(Case 1)
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\MyProjectRelease1.0\Client_App_Folder> ../Server_App_Folder/run_Server.exe -help  
(Proceeds to print out help)
```

But not with a command line like:

```
(Case 2)
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\MyProjectRelease1.0\Client_App_Folder\Client_App_Subfolder> ../../Server_App_Folder/run_Server.exe -help
(Waits a second then exits the program without any output)
```

*Note: Client_App_Subfolder has an identical name as Client_App_Folder due to unimportant reasons.*

Why is this happening? I may be mistaken, but I thought this did not happen under the exact same circumstances previously. I'm not finding much in the way of documentation about this phenomenon yet. I think this might have something to do with the up-directory `..\`s in the command. Slash direction seems to not alter the results in this case in powershell.

---

## Attempted Troubleshooting

Here's the first portion of `main.cpp`:

```cpp
// Other #includes above.

#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::filesystem::path cwd = std::filesystem::current_path() / "filename.txt";
    std::ofstream file(cwd.string());
    file.close();

    // ...proceed to parse command line arguments, etc.
}
```

This code results in outputting `filename.txt` in the `MyProject\Client_App_Folder` directory for the first case, but nothing for the second case.

Comment: My root issue has been solved; it apparently was me missing a `tzdata` folder that was referenced in a static global initializer from a path from a compile definition. I'm still interested in why the above behavior may have happened, as well as limitations on relative paths for calling .exe files.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  in a comment the author affirm that has found the solution.